# How to increase the maximum number of opened editors in IntelliJ?

Tags: configuration, grails, intellij-idea

I am building a grails-app with IntelliJ 9.0 and I am a huge fan of the CTR+TAB shortcut that switches between active editors.

However, by default, IntelliJ keeps ONLY 10 active editors opened at the same time. It is clearly not enough for me.

Do you know, if possible, how I can configure my IDE to have more active editors opened at the same time ?

Answer (score 577, accepted):

`Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | `Editor Tabs` | **Tab limit**.

[image: Type in tabs in search]

You may also want to increase the recent files limit in `Settings` | `Editor` | `General` | **Recent files limit** if you are using the **Recent Files** (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) feature.

Works for all IntelliJ IDEA platform based IDEs.

Comment: @li2 well Android Studio is basically a reskinned IntelliJ.

Comment: And RubyMine. ("And my axe!")

Comment: Is there a reason why there is a tab limit by default?

Comment: @Ruben9922 some users believe that the more open tabs you have, the less productive you are since you spend more time finding the tab you need, working without tabs at all can be more productive: http://hadihariri.com/2014/06/24/no-tabs-in-intellij-idea/.

Comment: Came here to look how to **decrease** :-)

Comment: the maximum value that you can set for the number of open tabs is 100. atleast that's for pycharm, but I assume it applies to all the IDEs by jetbrains.

Comment: @kapad there is a way to increase tab limit to more than 100 - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69169761/3174731

Comment: works flawlessly

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Recent Files, but I know Switcher `CTRL+TAB`, but one cannot find there something when typing...

Answer (score 24):

Same as best answer but with snapshots!! (windows 10 with IntelliJ Idea 2018.2.4):

[image: File -> Settings]
[image: Type in tabs in search]

Comment: actually, you can edit that answer instead of posting a new one