# How to setup Switcher in Intellij IDEA 10

Tags: settings, intellij-idea

I'm using the Switcher in Intellij IDEA to switch between editor tabs a lot. After I upgraded to version 10 the Switcher will only show 10 editor tabs, which is of course far too little. Does anybody know where I can increase this? I have scoured the IDE Settings but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10 files is the hardcoded limit for Switcher, you can't change it. Use Recent Files if you want to see more.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt answer. Not the one I was hoping for though. I have started using Recent files but it's not quite the same.

Comment: you can change the default. please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065756/4251722