# Intellij java editor: how to keep two files for editing

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Intellij java editor: how to keep two files for editing? For example, editing file foo.java and bar.java. When selecting foo.jar from the drop down list, the tab for bar.java disappear. When selecting bar.jar from the drop down list, the tab for foo.java disappear. How to make both tabs(foo.java and bar.java) visible at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can [split the editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Managing_Editor_Tabs.html#splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window) horizontally or vertically from the editor tab context menu to make multiple tabs visible at the same time.

Comment: Split will make editor window smaller. How to keep the two tabs from disappearing? Thanks.

Comment: You can have [a lot of tabs open at the same time](https://i.imgur.com/yVqoRax.png). Check [your limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065756/104891). Do you have it set to 1?

Comment: My question was misunderstood. Selecting one file will make another tab disappear.

Comment: How exactly do you select the files? Ctrl+E (Recent Files) opens files in the new tabs if the tab limit is > 1. Attach your [editor tabs settings](https://i.imgur.com/lakMjc1.png) to the question and describe the exact steps to reproduce the problem. Share a video of the issue.